# The argument type 'Stream<User>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<UserModel>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app in Flutter which I am new to but I am making progress in it. However, I'm stuck with the following error:

Error: The argument type 'Stream' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream'.
'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'
value: AuthServices().user,

Below is my **main.dart** code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
        value: AuthServices().user,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: WelcomeScreen(),
          routes: {
            WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
            LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
            RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
            ModuleScreen.id: (context) => ModuleScreen(),
            LectureListScreen.id: (context) => LectureListScreen(),
            SettingsScreen.id: (context) => SettingsScreen(),
            ResetPasswordScreen.id: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen(),
            ChangePasswordScreen.id: (context) => ChangePasswordScreen(),
            ChangeEmailScreen.id: (context) => ChangeEmailScreen(),
            PracticalListScreen.id: (context) => PracticalListScreen(),
            TestingListScreen.id: (context) => TestingListScreen(),
            TestScreen.id: (context) => TestScreen(),
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

and this is my **UserModel.dart** Code

```
class UserModel {
  final String uid;
  final bool isAnonymous;
  UserModel({this.uid, this.isAnonymous});
}

class UserData {
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String firstName;
  final String patronymic;
  final String lastName;
  final String studentID;

  UserData(
      {this.uid,
      this.email,
      this.firstName,
      this.patronymic,
      this.lastName,
      this.studentID});
}
```

I've tried everything possible and also looked online but could not find what the problem is. However, I think it has something to do with me not being able to get the correct 'context' when calling Authservices or parsing it so that it can accept the parameter.

Any assistance in this case by pointing me to what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: What is the type of `AuthServices().user`? It is `User`, right? I would say the error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `StreamProvider<UserModel>`, it means that you have to also provide it a value of type `UserModel`.

However, this `UserModel` is your own class, whereas what you are providing as `value` is `AuthServices().user` which is of type `Stream<User>` and not `Stream<UserModel>`.

First, convert the `User` into `UserModel` by having a named constructor, like this,

```
class UserModel {
  ....
  
  UserModel.fromUser(User user): UserModel(/* copy data from User into your UserModel */);
```

Then use it like this,

```
StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
  value: AuthServices().user.map<UserModel>((e) => UserModel.fromUser(e));,
  ....
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance. However, if you will permit me, I will like to ask where is your fromUser (User User) argument coming from. This needs to be a little clear for me. Sorry for asking this. Thank you in advance

Comment: It is a named constructor which you have to create. Open this https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors and scroll a bit down to see the explanation on named constructors. Is this what you were asking ?